# Random Variable X with mean 25

Tags: probability, expectation

If X is a nonnegative random variable with mean 25, what can be said about:

$E[X^3]$

$E[\sqrt{X}]$

$E[logX]$

$E[e^{-X}]$

My guess is that we need to know more information, like variance, to solve these expectations, but I have a feeling there might be some trick to them.

Comment: None of these can be *computed* but they can be *bounded*, either from above or from below. For example, $E(X^3)\geqslant$ $____$.

Comment: This looks like a Jensen's inequality question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely right that we need more information. The distribution of $X$ would be really helpful.

1.)  $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$ isn't necessarily guaranteed to exist if we only know the mean exists. See the Cauchy Distribution

2.) $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X})$ is only defined if $X$ is nonnegative almost surely. If it is, then by Jensen's Inequality we can say $\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{X}) \leq \sqrt{25}= 5$

3.) Again, all we can really say about this without any info is what's given by Jensen's inequality:  $\mathbb{E}(\log X) \leq \log \mathbb{E}(X) = \log(25)$

4.) We can apply Jensen's inequality to this as well, but its also the Moment Generating Function of $X$ evaluated at $s=-1$. Not all random variables have defined moment generating functions, however. See log-normal distribution.

Comment: Does Jensen's Inequality not pertain to part a, since X is nonnegative, we could take $E[X]^3$?

Comment: It does, but $X^3$ is a convex function, not a concave one. This means Jensen's inequality goes the other way, which doesn't really help us much.